# Does anyone really use Object initialize blocks in Java ? Was this used anywhere in Java API?

Tags: java

I know Java supports the object initialization blocks as shown below. The following code shows that the object initialize block always calls when the TestObjectInitialize instance has been created.

```
public class TestObjectInitialize {

    public int abc;

    //object initialize block
    {
      abc= 5;
    }

    public TestObjectInitialize() {

    }


    public static void main(String... args) {
          TestObjectInitialize toi = new TestObjectInitialize();
          System.out.println(toi.abc);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen people do this:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("key1", "value1");
    put("key2", "value2");
}};
```

It can be useful when you have a method

```
class Init {
    static int initFoo(Map<String, String> map) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
class FooBar {
    static int foo = Init.initFoo(new HashMap<String, String>() {{
                        put("key1", "value1");
                        put("key2", "value2");
                     }});
}
```

Comment: I never used that form as you are effectively creating a anynymous inner subclass. When doing code like that I always use a Builder interface with method chaining: `new MapBuilder<String, String>(new HashMap<String, String>).put("key1", "value2").put("key2", "value2").getMap()`

Comment: I don't like that particular use either but some people do. It is just an example. One can create a very expressive query syntax: Query query = new Query() {{ or(eq("x", 5), eq("x", 7)); }}

Answer (score 2):

I have used the `static` variant of it several times. e.g. it can be used to initialize a collection inside the class:

```
static List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
static {
    words.add("foo");
    words.add("bar");
}
```

The main benefit of this is that you keep declaration and initialization at the same place. A non static initializer still has the benefit that runs for all constructors without you having to chain the constructors.

```
public class Foo {
    int value;
    {
        value = getDefaultValue();
    }

    public Foo() {
    }
    public Foo(String something) {
    }
```

}

`value = getDefaultValue()` is executed regardless of the ctor being used.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone really use Object initialize blocks in Java ?

Answer is **Yes** . Now the Question is **Why?**
If you have final variables that may require programming logic to set them. Because , a final variable MUST be set before the constructor is called, and the only way to do this is to set it to some hard coded value during declaration , or to set it inside of an initializer block. Although , It can also be done in constructor But what if you have more than one constructor defined in clas?? Then you would have to initialize that final variable in every constructor which leads to code redundancy. For more information watch [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2).

> Was this used anywhere in Java?

I have not seen it in any API of Java till now . But we most of the times use it in codes like following way:

```
private final Set<String> VALID_CODES = new HashSet<String>() {{
    add("XZ13s");
    add("AB21/X");
    add("YYLEX");
    add("AR2D");
 }};
```